# AWS EKS Guestbook url not accessible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, aws-fargate

I'm on Win10 using cygwin and some other choco stuff, everything is installed and runs fine. I was able to install and run stuff from ecs-cli and fargate tutorial and compose too.

Now I'm trying EKS and set up cluster and guest book from the Getting Started with ekstcl here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started-eksctl.html

And then after cluster is set up here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/eks-guestbook.html

I created AWS Fargate-only Cluster.
I'm just following step by step by and in the end when I'm opening the url in the browser it says

```
This page isn’t working
a8b3bb2e121f511ea82cb1294ea943ee-1408939369.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

Step by step:

```
$ eksctl version
[ℹ]  version.Info{BuiltAt:"", GitCommit:"", GitTag:"0.11.1"}

$ eksctl create cluster --name eks-snafu --version 1.14 --region us-east-1 --fargate
[ℹ]  eksctl version 0.11.1
[ℹ]  using region us-east-1
[ℹ]  setting availability zones to [us-east-1f us-east-1b]
[ℹ]  subnets for us-east-1f - public:192.168.0.0/19 private:192.168.64.0/19
[ℹ]  subnets for us-east-1b - public:192.168.32.0/19 private:192.168.96.0/19
[ℹ]  using Kubernetes version 1.14
[ℹ]  creating EKS cluster "eks-snafu" in "us-east-1" region with Fargate profile
[ℹ]  if you encounter any issues, check CloudFormation console or try 'eksctl utils describe-stacks --region=us-east-1 --cluster=eks-snafu'
[ℹ]  CloudWatch logging will not be enabled for cluster "eks-snafu" in "us-east-1"
[ℹ]  you can enable it with 'eksctl utils update-cluster-logging --region=us-east-1 --cluster=eks-snafu'
[ℹ]  Kubernetes API endpoint access will use default of {publicAccess=true, privateAccess=false} for cluster "eks-snafu" in "us-east-1"
[ℹ]  1 task: { create cluster control plane "eks-snafu" }
[ℹ]  building cluster stack "eksctl-eks-snafu-cluster"
[ℹ]  deploying stack "eksctl-eks-snafu-cluster"
[✔]  all EKS cluster resources for "eks-snafu" have been created
[✔]  saved kubeconfig as "<MY WIN HOME>/.kube/config"
[ℹ]  creating Fargate profile "fp-default" on EKS cluster "eks-snafu"
[ℹ]  created Fargate profile "fp-default" on EKS cluster "eks-snafu"
[ℹ]  "coredns" is now schedulable onto Fargate
[ℹ]  "coredns" is now scheduled onto Fargate
[ℹ]  "coredns" pods are now scheduled onto Fargate
[ℹ]  kubectl command should work with "<MY WIN HOME>/.kube/config", try 'kubectl get nodes'
[✔]  EKS cluster "eks-snafu" in "us-east-1" region is ready

$ kubectl get svc -o wide
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE    SELECTOR
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.100.0.1   <none>        443/TCP   7m7s   <none>

$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/examples/master/guestbook-go/redis-master-controller.json
replicationcontroller/redis-master created

$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/examples/master/guestbook-go/redis-master-service.json
service/redis-master created

$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/examples/master/guestbook-go/redis-slave-controller.json
replicationcontroller/redis-slave created

$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/examples/master/guestbook-go/redis-slave-service.json
service/redis-slave created

$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/examples/master/guestbook-go/guestbook-controller.json
replicationcontroller/guestbook created

$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/examples/master/guestbook-go/guestbook-service.json
service/guestbook created

$ kubectl get services -o wide
NAME           TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP                                                               PORT(S)          AGE   SELECTOR
guestbook      LoadBalancer   10.100.201.159   a8b3bb2e121f511ea82cb1294ea943ee-1408939369.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com   3000:32600/TCP   12s   app=guestbook
kubernetes     ClusterIP      10.100.0.1       <none>                                                                    443/TCP          14m   <none>
redis-master   ClusterIP      10.100.133.248   <none>                                                                    6379/TCP         43s   app=redis,role=master
redis-slave    ClusterIP      10.100.198.154   <none>                                                                    6379/TCP         26s   app=redis,role=slave
```

Now I'm opening this:
http://a8b3bb2e121f511ea82cb1294ea943ee-1408939369.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com:3000

And get nothing :(

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong. However, when using EKS on Fargate you have to [consider](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/fargate.html#fargate-considerations) certain things. This includes, as of time of writing, that only ALB is supported. The Guestbook example [uses](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/blob/a32bf5c3e9e8065176238df7bd4b00701fce4106/guestbook-go/guestbook-service.json#L20) a service type `LoadBalancer`, causing the creation of a classic load balancer, which is, ATM, not supported in EKS on Fargate.

Comment: Thanks Michael! Any recommendations what needs to be done to run this example? I'm very new to these things and have got a lot to learn yet.

Comment: Unfortunately this example won't work unless you use an Ingress resource. I'd suggest you pick something from https://hub.helm.sh (that doesn't use CLB or persistent volumes).

Answer (score 1):

Michael Hausenblas is correct: the guestbook example doesn't work with a fargate cluster.

To set up a Linux-Only cluster, you can follow the instructions from the page you link (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started-eksctl.html).  Just select "Cluster with Linux-only workloads" instead of " AWS Fargate-only cluster" when you get to "Create your Amazon EKS cluster and worker nodes".  I copied the command below for convenience.

eksctl create cluster \

--name prod \

--region region-code \

--nodegroup-name standard-workers \

--node-type t3.medium \

--nodes 3 \

--nodes-min 1 \

--nodes-max 4 \

--ssh-access \

--ssh-public-key my-public-key.pub \

--managed

P.S.  Realize this question is a few months old, and marked as accepted, but I had the same issue and figured other beginners might want more explicit instructions.

P.S.S. This might be better as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation to comment yet!